# JSF/Icefaces RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I am trying to write a component in JSF to read legacy JSP files. I am using RequestDispatcher.include to do this...The only problem is that externalContext.getRequest().getRequestDispatcher(...) returns an UnsupportedOperationException in Icefaces.

Is there a way round this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The life cycle seems to cause that exception. http://blogs.oracle.com/jayashri/entry/when_and_how_to_redirect